# connecting javascript secure websocket client to python websocket asyncio server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm having trouble establishing connection between javascript websocket client and python server (with the asyncio and websocket module). When i used the simple websocket (unsecure) the connection is working fine but when i'm trying to use the secure websocket (wss) i get an error:

```
   WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:6169/' failed: Error in connection 
   establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

**my server code:**

```
async def app(websocket, path):
    while True :
        data = await websocket.recv()
        if (data== "close"):
            print("connection with client closed.")
            break
        data = data.encode()
        arr = data.split("~".encode())
        for i in range(0,4):
            arr[i]=arr[i].decode()
        resualt=algo(arr)
        await websocket.send(resualt)

server = websockets.serve(app, '0.0.0.0', 6169)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**my client code:**

```
var st=password+"~"+url+"~"+clientid+"~"+option;
                    if ('WebSocket' in window){
                        var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:6169/");
                        socket.onopen = function (evt) {
                            socket.send(st);
                        };
                        socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                            alert("scrool extension page down to see the password");
                            $('#res').val(evt.data);
                            socket.send("close");
                        };
                        socket.onerror = function (evt) {
                            alert("the error is: "+evt.data);
                        };
                    }
                    else {
                       alert("web socket is not supported")
                    }
```

when i replaced this line :

```
    var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:6169/");
```

with this one:

```
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:6169/");
```

everthing is working fine.

if somebody knows what is my mistake or how to succesfuly establish a secure connection between js client with websocket library and python server with asyncio and web socket module, please help. I have searched all over the web for an example that works but i couldn't find one.

I also tried to enable TLS in my server  by changing my code to this :

```
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH) 
    context.load_default_certs(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH) 
    server = websockets.serve(app, '0.0.0.0', 6169, ssl=context)
```

but it still does'nt work and give me the following error:

```
    WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:6169/' failed: Error in 
    connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED –
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're setting up a TLS-based websocket server. Take a look at the [`ssl`](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.server.serve) option.

Comment: first thank you for the quick respond. I have read the API's and it says there that if the ssl argument is'nt provided it will load the default python sslcontext. I tried also to do it my self by changing my code to this :

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_default_certs(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
start_server = websockets.serve(app, '0.0.0.0', 6169, ssl=context)


but it still does'nt work and give me the following error:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:6169/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: To be honest, I know next to nothing about TLS in Python, so hopefully someone with more knowledge can help you out there :)